# Receiving 1 row from joined (1 to many) postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, one-to-many, postgresql-9.1

I have this problem:

- I have 2 major tables (apartments, tenants) that have a connection of 1 to many (1 apartment, many tenants).
- I'm trying to pull all my building apartments, but with one of his tenants.
- The preffered tenant is the one who have ot=2 (there are 2 possible values: 1 or 2).

I tried to use subqueries but in postgresql it doesn't let you return more than 1 column.
I don't know how to solve it. Here is my latest code:

```
SELECT a.apartment_id, a.apartment_num, a.floor, at.app_type_desc_he, tn.otype_desc_he, tn.e_name
FROM 
  public.apartments a INNER JOIN public.apartment_types at ON
  at.app_type_id = a.apartment_type INNER JOIN 
    (select t.apartment_id, t.building_id, ot.otype_id, ot.otype_desc_he, e.e_name
     from   public.tenants t INNER JOIN public.ownership_types ot ON
        ot.otype_id = t.ownership_type INNER JOIN entities e ON
        t.entity_id = e.entity_id
     ) tn ON
  a.apartment_id = tn.apartment_id AND tn.building_id = a.building_id
WHERE 
  a.building_id = 4 AND tn.building_id=4
ORDER BY
  a.apartment_num ASC, 
  tn.otype_id DESC
```

Thanx in advance

Comment: Please, include the definition of the tables and some sample data.

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT a.apartment_id, a.apartment_num, a.floor
      ,at.app_type_desc_he, tn.otype_desc_he, tn.e_name
FROM   public.apartments a
JOIN   public.apartment_types at ON at.app_type_id = a.apartment_type
LEFT JOIN  (
    SELECT t.apartment_id, t.building_id, ot.otype_id
          ,ot.otype_desc_he, e.e_name
    FROM   public.tenants t
    JOIN   public.ownership_types ot ON ot.otype_id = t.ownership_type
    JOIN   entities e ON t.entity_id = e.entity_id
    ORDER  BY (ot.otype_id = 2) DESC
    LIMIT  1
    ) tn ON (tn.apartment_id, tn.building_id)=(a.apartment_id, a.building_id) 
WHERE  a.building_id = 4
AND    tn.building_id = 4
ORDER  BY a.apartment_num;  -- , tn.otype_id DESC -- pointless
```

Crucial part emphasized.

This works in either case.

- If there are tenants for an apartment, exactly 1 will be returned.
- If there is one (or more) tenant of `ot.otype_id = 2`, it will be one of that type.
- If there are no tenants, the apartment is still returned.

If, for `ot.otype_id` ...

> there are 2 possible values: 1 or 2

... you can simplify to:

```sql
ORDER  BY ot.otype_id DESC
```

---

#### Debug query

Try removing the `WHERE` clauses from the base query and change

```sql
JOIN   public.apartment_types
```

to

```sql
LEFT JOIN   public.apartment_types
```

and add them back one by one to see which condition excludes all rows.

Do `at.app_type_id` and `a.apartment_type` really match?

Comment: Thank you Erwin for your fast reply. I have tried your offer but I don't get any result at all. I did found a work around with ROW(select .... ). Unfortunately, I'm not succeeding pull it data with PHP. Any knowledge?

Comment: @user1488098: I added some pointers for debugging. Should be simple, but it's just guesswork for under-informed outsiders.

Comment: @user1488098: It really makes it a lot easier on those trying to help if you provide the statements to construct the tables and load enough sample data to test. Without it people need to do a lot more work, and may need to make some guesses that could be off-target, reducing their ability to provide you with what you want.